# How to remote connect to linux/WASv7 with JConsole?

Tags: java, linux, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to remotely connect to a server with JConsole to monitor & make use of the MBeans registered there.

I can VNC onto the server and run JConsole locally with "localhost:8050", but any attempt to connect remotely, via ip address or hostname, fails in a NullPointerException.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:281)
>
> at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:227)
>
> at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:334)
>
> at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:296)
>
> at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:280)

I've read through the other excellent q&a's here and on many other websites. I've tried opening ports with iptables, editing the hosts file. ssl and authentication are disabled, local.only is disabled. I've disabled the proxy and tried the JMXServiceURL too, to no avail.

How come i am able to run JConsole & connect locally but not remotely?

I even have a second server, running win2008 & tomcat, that plays along perfectly!

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the remote management ports are open using netstat or lsof?

Answer (score 1):

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<port no> \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<server ip>"
```

Try to use this setting on your application server. It worked for me on Tomcat.